# How to allow two threads to share a global variable in WinAPI?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I have two threads that are created using [CreateThread()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx), and I have a global variable that one thread writes to, and the other thread reads from.

Now based on my understanding, the compiler and/or the CPU can do all sorts of optimizations, which could mean for example that when I write a value to the variable, the value can be written in some cache and not written directly to memory (and hence the other thread will not be able to see it).

I have read that I can wrap the code that access the variable in a critical section, but the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530(v=vs.85).aspx) says that a critical section will only enforce mutual exclusion, and does not say anything about enforcing writing directly to memory and reading directly from memory.

*Note that I do not which to use the **volatile** keyword, I want to know how this is done in pure WinAPI (as I could use a language other than C in a later time).*

Comment: What type of variable is it exactly? For 32-bit and 64-bit integers, the Win32 API has an [Interlocked Variable Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122.aspx) API to handle this situation.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau It could be anything (primitive type, struct instance, array).

Comment: As long as you protect *all* accesses to the variable (from either thread) with the same critical section object, you should be okay... changes made in one thread while it has the critical section will be visible to the other when *that* thread has the critical section.  If that weren't true, they wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: and that will work fine even if the data is written to a cache first, since the read should get the cached data.

Comment: @Dmitr The documentation says that a critical section only enforces mutual exclusion, where did you read that a critical section allows a thread to see changes made by another thread?

Comment: It isn't documented (that I know of) but it is well-known.  Microsoft aren't great on the rigorous documentation front.  They are, however, pretty good at backwards compatibility, the sheer number of programs that would break if critical sections stopped acting as memory barriers means that it need not be of practical concern.

Comment: (This isn't language independent, mind you, or at least not inherently.  The API can control CPU optimizations, but there's no way for it to control what optimizations a compiler does.  *In  practice,* I *think* a compiler that reordered memory operations across a call to a critical section function would have to be considered pathological, but there might be edge cases in the weirder hypothetical languages.)

Comment: "the value can be written in some cache and not written directly to memory " - what is cache can be for *memory* ? for local variable (in stack)  compiler with optimization can use CPU register, but this is because no any another thread can access it - even if another thread execute same function in concurrent - every have unique stack and own copy of this variable. but for global variable compilers never use registers because they understand - this variable can be assigned by different threads. so all changes direct write to memory as is.

Comment: @Dmitri - compilers (*CL* how minimum, but think all) understand that global variable  can be accessed from any part of code, from any thread - and *never* use registers as temporary storage for this variables. about CPU cache - if we use interlocked functions (with *lock* prefix) here synchronization is done by *lock*. if used some os synchronization like crit-sections, read-write locks, etc - it also effective work as memory barrier

Comment: @RbMm, that's not true.  Most C compilers will cache global variables in registers when necessary for optimizations.  For example, consider a loop like `for (n = 0, j = 0; n < size; n++) data[n] = j++;` and you will find that the compiler only writes the value of `n` and `j` to memory at the end of the loop, and certainly never checks during the loop to see if another thread has changed them.  During the loop, both `n` and `j` are kept in registers.

Comment: (Tested on Visual Studio 2010, in Release mode.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - ok, yes. in this example `CL` view that we not care about any synchronizations. but try bit modify this example - call in loop any external function, about compiler have no knowledge - and `CL` just drop any optimization with registers (it can still use nonvolatile registers for `n` and `j` but *not use* ) try for example next loop - `for (n = 0, j = 0; n < size; n++) { GetTickCount(); data[n] = j++; }`

Comment: @RbMm, yes, in practice any C/C++ compiler I've ever heard of will assume that any external function might access or modify any global variable, and ensure that the values aren't cached across the call.  Most other languages are probably the same.  It is however possible to imagine a compiler that "knows" which API calls don't modify global variables and takes advantage of that.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - very important - are we call any external function inside expression. if no - compiler can consider whole code snippet as internal atomic term - he understand that we not care about any synchronization *inside* this snippet and let optimize. if we call external functions *before* and *after* this 'term' - this not break optimization. but any call *inside* expression - just break any optimization (despite that compiler still can use nonvolatile registers (which will be not changed in during external call).

Comment: really in some extreme case CL can mistake with optimization and produce unpleasant mistakes. hard topic and need say about specific code for details

Comment: Folks, let's get back on topic. OP wants to write from one thread and to read from another. Is there anything that volatile won't do?

Comment: @SergeiVorobiev, that use of `volatile` is a Microsoft-specific extension, not part of the standard, and in recent MS compilers can be turned off.

Comment: "the value can be written in some cache and not written directly to memory (and hence the other thread will not be able to see it)." - if the variable is actually written to cache or memory and read from cache or memory, and the write or read is inherently atomic (32 bit variable on 32 bit boundary), then [cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) will eliminate cache issues. There's no guarantee about the timing, and depending on how the variable is declared, it could be kept in a register in the write and/or read threads.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN explicitly states that critical sections are memory barriers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686355(v=vs.85).aspx