# Does a critical section makes sure that shared variables of any data type modified by one thread becomes visible to the other threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I want to share some variables between multiple threads, the shared variables can be of any data type (primitive data types, array, instance of a struct or class, etc.).

If I enclosed the code that accesses these shared variables in a critical section, will the changes made by one thread becomes visible to the other threads?

I know that for primitive data types, the critical section approach works, but I am not sure about the other data types, even though I believe that the answer is yes (because the CPU does not care about data types, it is just dealing with bits).

Comment: With a modern multi-tasking protected system like Windows, all threads in a single process can access all the data in the process. All non-local variables are already "shared". They are "visible" from all threads in the process. Perhaps if you elaborate on the actual problem you're having we might be able to help you better?

Comment: I think the question is rather about caching problems. Variables shared by multiple threads shoud be declared `volatile` to make sure that all threads see the updates immediately.

Comment: @Aconcagua  In standard C++ `volatile` has nothing to do with threading.  MS has an extension (retained due to legacy code) that makes `volatile` behave the way you suggest.  Modern C++ application should use `std::atomic` or synchronisation functions. See: _"ISO Compliant"_ in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx

Comment: You already asked this question I think. Perhaps even more than once.

Comment: @David Heffernan No I did not, that other question was about primitive data types, that's why I said in this question: *"I know that for primitive data types, the critical section approach works".*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, "Modern?" That's pretty much been how threads have been defined since 1980-something:  What separates threads from processes has always been that threads share a common address space and common resources such as file handles and network sockets, while processes are isolated from one another.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, "visibility" is a big issue when you're running multiple threads on a multi-CPU host.  Sure, all threads see all the same variables, but they do not necessarily agree upon when (or in what order) the _updates_ to those variables happen.  The "memory model" for a programming system tells you when you can rely on updates made by one thread becoming visible to other threads:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)

Comment: Memory is memory. Doesn't matter whether it's a simple integer or a complex structure. It's just memory.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the answers to the other question do not address, the fact that c++ is unaware of threads unless explicitly told - via 'volatile' (older) or now std::atomic - that the variables being touched should be read from memory and not optimized out. All the memory barriers and cache synchronization in the world is not going to help you if the compiler (incorrectly) determined it didn't need to read the memory at all.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact the question is still a duplicate. I'm sure that particular issue has been mentioned numerous times in the asker recent posts.

Comment: OP worried about CPUs cache unsync - when one thread modify data in CPU cache, and another thread can read from own CPU cache yet old data. `becomes visible to the other threads` need understand memory modification make by some CPU became visible for all another CPUs. for this and exist Memory Barriers and windows synchronization api make this barrier

Comment: @ChrisBecke, that was discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42660921/886887).

Answer (score 0):

Since the point of a CriticalSection is to serialize access different threads/cores, you can expect the functions to do whatever it takes to ensure proper shared access across threads. This will include things like memory barriers.

Comment: To be more specific:  When one thread locks a mutex, it should be able to see all of the updates that were made by some other thread before the other thread _unlocked_ the same mutex.

Answer (score 0):

yes, enter/exit critical effective synchronize CPU cashes - global variables - because in this functions always execute instruction with *lock* prefix - this is key point.

read for example about [`KeMemoryBarrier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552971(v=vs.85).aspx) (this is equal to [`MemoryBarrier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684208(v=vs.85).aspx) macro)

> In addition, the xchg instruction implicitly includes the **lock**
>   prefix, which forces the processor hardware to complete the memory
>   operations for all instructions that precede the xchg instruction
>   before it initiates memory operations for instructions that follow the
>   xchg instruction.

as result and `EnterCriticalSection` / `LeaveCriticalSection` and any interlocked functions (which use *lock* prefix) effective here. note that `KeMemoryBarrier` do `lock xchg` on random memory (*really `lock xchg [esp],eax` but this is enough*)

also read [Memory Barriers/Fences](https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/07/memory-barriersfences.html)

> **Atomic Instructions and Software Locks** Atomic instructions, such as the “lock ...” instructions on x86, are effectively a full barrier
>   as they lock the memory sub-system to perform an operation and have
>   guaranteed total order, even across CPUs.  Software locks usually
>   employ memory barriers, or atomic instructions, to achieve visibility
>   and preserve program order.